# How can i sum up the number of lines for all source code in BASH?

Tags: bash, count

I want to find out the total number of lines of code for a given directory (include sub-directory), for example, search for all *.php files and sum up each one using ***wc -l***

How can I combine commands (using pipe) and achieve this on BASH shell? Simpler the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$ find . -name "*.php" | xargs wc
```

?

Comment: you may want to add `-l`

Comment: And pipe with `tail -1`